# tiles of map and css can not be loaded while cypress test run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, here-api, cypress

at first thanks for the great maps, API and documentation.
We are building a single page app and we are using the here maps for that. To test our app we use [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/).
When we first implement the test everything runs fine and we got nice test results. But since yesterday we are facing the following problem. When cypress runs our test, the css and the tiles can not be loaded.
For The css we get an 500 response, which seems to be a little bit strange.
For the tiles we get an `failed` as response, which I don´t know what that could mean. 
[cypress log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj5yW.png)

When we run the app by itself, everything seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any detail in the body of the 500 response?

Comment: unfortunately not. There is only the message `Failed To Load Response Data`

Comment: Nor in the javascript console? Can add in the question the whole http request url made for the css file?

Comment: Hi @MichaelP.Bazos sorry for my very late response. We were able to determine what the problem was. 
The problem was that the compay proxy does not allow that the cypress test runner communicates outside the company network.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the company proxy does not allow the cypress test runner to communicate outside the company network.

So check your proxy if you face a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use  "cypress": "3.3.1", there is a proxy setting

[image]